# How to create a page from the id parameter in the url

Tags: firebase, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to create a single page from the id that is passed as a parameter.

my routes structure:

[image]

When I pass the mouse over an item in my list I get the id of the firebase document so I need to create a page to show the data in the documents based on their ids.

```
http://localhost:3000/category/rent/541KqSMHpU17QuYLihFs
```

id:

```
541KqSMHpU17QuYLihFs
```

My listItem component:

```js
<script>
    export let listing
    export let id
    export let handleDelete
    import DeleteIcon from '../../static/assets/svg/deleteIcon.svg'
</script>

<li class="categoryListing">
    <a href={`/category/${listing.type}/${id}`} class="categoryListingLink">
        <img src={listing.imgUrls[0]} alt={listing.name} class="categoryListingImg" />
        <div class="categoryListingDetails">
            <p class="categoryListingLocation">
                {listing.location}
            </p>
            <p class="CategoryListingName">
                {listing.name}
            </p>
            <p class="categoryListingPrice">
                ${listing.offer
                    ? listing.discountedPrice.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.')
                    : listing.regularPrice.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.')}
                {listing.type === 'rent' ? '/ por mês' : ''}
            </p>
            <div class="categoryListingInfoDiv">
                <img src="/assets/svg/bedIcon.svg" alt="cama" />
                <p class="categoryListingInfoText">
                    {listing.bedrooms > 1 ? `${listing.bedrooms} camas` : `${listing.bedrooms} cama`}
                </p>
                <img src="/assets/svg/bathtubIcon.svg" alt="banheiro" />
                <p class="categoryListingInfoText">
                    {listing.bathrooms > 1
                        ? `${listing.bathrooms} banheiros`
                        : `${listing.bathrooms} banheiro`}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    {#if handleDelete}
        <DeleteIcon
            class="removeIcon"
            fill="rgb(231, 76, 60)"
            onClick={() => {
                handleDelete(listing.id, listing.name)
            }}
        />
    {/if}
</li>
```

The important thing here is it:

```
<a href={`/category/${listing.type}/${id}`} class="categoryListingLink">
```

How do I make my [listingId] slug be the id page?

my [listingId].svelte so far:

```js
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores'
    const listingId = $page.params.listingId
    import { db } from '../../../../firebase.config.js'

    // get the id parameter from the url

</script>
```

Happy new Year!!

Comment: some advice, I would always use 'export let data: PageData' because it is all typed so you get intellesense on it. if your expect a param you can see it there unless there is something wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a little trouble understanding your question at first.

As it stands now, your URIs are in the shape `/category/id/[listingId]`, so `http://localhost:3000/category/rent/541KqSMHpU17QuYLihFs` won't get matched. What you need are URIs in the shape of `/category/[id]/[listingId]`. So you need to rename your `id` directory to `[id]` in order to make it dynamic.

You will then be able to retrieve the `id` the same way you do `listingId`:

```js
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores'
    const { id, listingId }  = $page.params
    import { db } from '../../../../firebase.config.js'

    // do stuff

</script>
```

With the above URL as an example, `id` will hold the value `'rent'` and `listingId` will hold the value `'541KqSMHpU17QuYLihFs'`.

Hope this answers your question (and happy new year to you as well!)

**Edit:** a better, more explicit name for the `[id]` parameter would be `[listingCategory]` and would improve the readability of your code/the understanding of your intent.